# Atualização .NET Framework para uma versão maior que a 4.0

Tags: .net, web.config

Eu abri uma solicitação para a área de TI atualizar meu site para a versão 4.5 ou superior do .NET Framework.

Disseram que o servidor tem a versão 4.5 já, o problema é que o meu site continua retornando o seguinte, no rodapé da página de erro:

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.2053.0

*Como eu faço para alterar a versão do .NET Framework no meu site? Tem como configurar pela Web.Config para usar a versão 4.5 ou superior?*

A impressão que eu tenho é que eles não sabem o que estão fazendo e acham que a instalação no servidor garante que o site está usando a versão solicitada por mim.

O meu Web.Config está assim;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Isso não resolveu nada ainda.

Ainda mandaram uma imagem que eu não consigo fazer upload aqui, então vou tentar escrever (não tem cabeçalho):

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------------------+-----+
|  .NET v4.5  |  Started  |   v4.0   |  Integrated  |  ApplicationPollD...  |  0  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------------------+-----+
```

Comment: aquela versão 4.0.3.0319 ali é a versão do clr, não do .net...

Comment: Como já foi dito é a versão do CLR, e a versão do ASP.Net geralmente segue a do .Net, então provavelmente tem o .Net 4.7 instalado, e não tem como pegar por código diretamente, pode tentar pegar no registro se o acesso não estiver bloqueado como explicado [na documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed), sendo que não tem como ter mais de uma versão do .Net 4.X instalado então não tem como configurar o site pra usar uma versão específica

Comment: Tudo bem, gente, mas por que minha API funciona bem com localhost no VS Studio, mas não roda quando eu publico? Só aparece o seguinte: `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
</Error>`.

Comment: Pessoal, quando habilitei os erros detalhados, mostrou erro de conexão. Corrigi e deu certo. Obrigado pelo apoio.